# Does $x^2+y^2=-1$ have solution in $p$ adic number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

$x^2+y^2=-1$ has solution in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-2})$ since $(3\sqrt{-2})^2+(\sqrt{17})^2=-1$.

But in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$, I cannot find solution $x^2+y^2=-1$ until now and I guess this has no solution.
How can I prove $x^2+y^2=-1$ does not have solution in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$?

This can be thought of calculation of Hilbert symbol over quadratic number field.
In $\Bbb{Q}_2$, from discussion in [Does $17x^4+y^2=-1$ have solution in $\Bbb{Q}_2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730095/does-17x4y2-1-have-solution-in-bbbq-2/4730239?noredirect=1#comment10026536_4730239), there is no rational points in $\Bbb{Q}_2$.

If some general theory is know, reference is also appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I modified typo.

Comment: Hint: what are the roots of $z^2+z=-1$?

Comment: @Aphelli. Do you mean roots in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$ ? If $z$ is not a unit, taking 2 adic valuation of $z^2=-1-z$, $2v(z)=min\{0,v(z)\}$.But this proves $z$ is a unit, contradiction. Thus, roots are units. But I cannot proceed from here.

Comment: This is a quadratic equation. What is the exact expression for $z$?

Comment: $z^2+z+1=(z-\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})(z-\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2} )$ ,thus roots arę  in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: But does it have to do with $x^2+y^2=-1$ ?

Comment: You are asking about the Stufe (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_(algebra)) of a $p$-adic field. Highly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3965273/96384. The only case left open there is that of extensions of $\mathbb Q_2$ of degree $2m$ with $m \ge 2$.

Comment: @Aphelli. Let $a=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}, -1=a+a^2=a^4+a^2$, thus my question's equation has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965273/over-which-extensions-of-mathbb-q-2-is-x2y2z2-isotropic) for more on $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in extensions of $\mathbf Q_2$. There is a link to that MSE page in one of the comments, but it also provides an answer to your question.